# Visual Studio 2015 - Http does not exist in the namespace System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, import, namespaces, abstract-class

I have 2 projects, in 2 different instances of Visual Studio 2015, using the same .NET Framework Version (4.5.2) with the Startup Object well set up and in the first one, which is this one:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;

namespace ExampleRemoting
{
    public class DateTimeServer : MarshalByRefObject, IDisposable
    {
        public DateTimeServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DateTime server activated");
        }

        ~DateTimeServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DateTime server Object Destroyed.");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public String MyMethod(String name)
        {
            String strMessage = "Hi " + name + ". Here is the current DateTime: " + DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(strMessage);
            return strMessage;
        }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            HttpChannel channel = new HttpChannel(9999);
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel);
            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
            Type.GetType("ExampleRemoting.DateTimeServer,Listing23.9"), "SayDateTime", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
            System.Console.WriteLine("press <enter> to exit.");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public String MyMethod(String name)
        {
            String strMessage = "Hi " + name + ". Here is the current DateTime: " + DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine(strMessage);
            return strMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

I get error in the `using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;` line, and I get this error: `Http does not exist in the namespace System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http;`

I have copied and pasted the same code after openning this project: https://github.com/nccgroup/VulnerableDotNetHTTPRemoting/tree/master/C%23-Sample-Project-Client-Server, and it turns out that I don't get the error anymore. That project also used the same `Http` class without any problem.

Any idea about what is happenning here?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Does your project have a reference to `System.Runtime.Remoting.dll` ?

Comment: If you are talking about the "Reference Paths" tab, I don't have any in either one of the projects, plus, the `System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;` doesn't throw an error so I don't think the mistake is in here.

Comment: Depending on your project type, it would be visible under *References* or *Dependencies* in your Solution Explorer. The code you're trying to run lives in that dll so if it's not referenced, that's the error you'll get. Either way, try adding a reference to that dll, it will either be in NuGet or just in the add reference dialog box

Comment: Dude, that was epic, just by adding a reference in `Project > Add Reference` to `System.Runtime.Remoting` solved the problem. Thank you so much